# customise keyboard in wp8 apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

My aim is to include a textbox which can accept only one among seven characters (S,A,B,C,D,E,U).
Is there any possible way of customising the onscreen keyboard.
I know there are built-in layouts for entering text,numbers,chat,formula like the one specified in

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh393998%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

But i need the keyboard to contain only these 7 letters.
Any possible solutions?

**Edit:**
I made it possible by disabling the other keys in the onscreen keyboard. Found no other work arounds.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do it using the built-in SIP provider.
What you can do, however, is to create your own fake `TextBox` and your own keyboard like control. After all, you only need to input 7 letters.

EDIT: I just realized that only a single value needs be selected. For that purposes, use [`ListPicker`](http://phone.codeplex.com/) because that is the standard control for picking a single item.

Comment: Will it be a good idea to use common slider to vary between these seven values and reflecting its change in a textbox.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that you need just *one* value. Use `ListPicker` for that instead of `TextBox`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported out-of-the-box.

You would need to create your own visual keyboard and logics(constraints, limitations, RegEx, etc...)